# How to get size of Azure Container in PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

Similar to this question [How to get size of Azure CloudBlobContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901965/how-to-get-size-of-azure-cloudblobcontainer)

How can one get the size of the Azure Container in PowerShell. I can see a suggested script at https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Billable-Size-of-32175802 but want to know if there is a simpler way to do in PowerShell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Azure PowerShell, you can list all blobs in the container with `Get-AzureStorageBlob` with Container and Context parameter like:

```
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName youraccountname -storageAccountKey youraccountkey

$blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container containername -Context $ctx
```

Output of `Get-AzureStorageBlob` is an array of `AzureStorageBlob`, which has a property with name `ICloudBlob`, you can get blob length in its  `Properties`, then you can sum length of all blobs to get content length of the container.

Comment: A little warning: if a blob container is too large, you will eventually get an OutOfMemoryException using this code. You can solve this by implementing MaxCount and ContinuationToken to retrieve the blobs in batches

Answer (score 2):

The following PowerShell script is a simple translation of the c# code in the accepted answer of the question [How to get size of Azure CloudBlobContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901965/how-to-get-size-of-azure-cloudblobcontainer). Hope this suit your needs.

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
$accountName = "<your storage account name>"
$keyValue = "<your storage account key>"
$containerName = "<your container name>"

$storageCred = New-Object Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials ($accountName, $keyValue)

$storageAccount = New-Object Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount ($storageCred, $true)

$container = $storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference($containerName)

$length = 0

$blobs = $container.ListBlobs($null, $true, [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobListingDetails]::None, $null, $null)

$blobs | ForEach-Object {$length = $length + $_.Properties.Length}

$length
```

Note: the leading `Login-AzureRmAccount` command will load the necessary .dll for you. If you do know the path of "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll", you can replace it by `[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("$StorageLibraryPath") | Out-Null`. The path is usually like this "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure.NET SDK\v2.7\ToolsRef\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll"

Comment: Thanks that gives a good idea. I have avoided Login-AzureRmAccount by using the storage account key and context

Comment: The `Login-AzureRmAccount` is not for login at all. It's for loading the library. It's not necessary if you know the path of the .dll file. @EmmaZhu-MSFT's answer is greate. She's using pure PowerShell commands. And, my answer is showing that if you get a piece of C# code, you always can translate it into a PowerShell script. Another way to solve the problem.

Comment: I wanted to upvote your answer but I don't have enough points yet to do that:)

Comment: No problem. @EmmaZhu-MSFT's answer is already accepted. Her answer is also great.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution I just hammered through today.  Above examples didn't give me what I wanted which was (1) a byte sum of all blobs in a container and (2) a list of each blob + path + size so that it can be used to compare the results to a du -b on linux (origin).

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
$ResourceGroupName = ""
$StorageAccountName = ""
$StorageAccountKey = ""
$ContainerName = "" 

New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey
# Don't NEED the Resource Group but, without it, fills the screen with red as it search each RG...
$size = 0
$blobs = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $StorageAccountName -ErrorAction Ignore | Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName
foreach ($blob in $blobs) {$size = $size + $blob.length}
write-host "The container is $size bytes."
$properties = @{Expression={$_.Name};Label="Name";width=180}, @{Expression={$_.Length};Label="Bytes";width=80}
$blobs | ft $properties | Out-String -width 800 | Out-File -Encoding ASCII AzureBlob_files.txt
```

I then moved the file to Linux to do some flip flopping of it and the find output to create a list of files to input into blobxfer.  Solution to a different problem, but perhaps a suitable solution for your needs as well.