# Azure Blob Storage : CloudBlockBlob.downloadToByteArray(byte[] buffer, int bufferOffset) how to set size of buffer

Tags: java, azure-blob-storage

Let's say there is blob in Azure Blob Storage, which I want to download as byte[]. This can be achieved by getting the reference to the blob and downloading as shown below in the below snippet:

```
CloudBlobContainer container = getCloudBlobContainer(containerName);
CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(blobName);
```

Now I can use `blob.downloadToByteArray(byte[] buffer, int bufferOffset)`
I have gone through some links where it is suggested that **buffer** is to be initialised with the size which is more than **sum of the blob size and bufferOffset**. Now **bufferOffset** will be **0** but how do I derive stored blob size. Any suggestion here.

Comment: Is that you want to get the blob size?

Comment: I don't want to get the blob size in the first place as I want to download the whole content.

Comment: If you want to download the whole content, you can try to use `downloadToFile ` method :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblob.downloadtofile?view=azure-java-legacy

Comment: I am aware of those options, I need byte[] so do not want to download it as file. For that sake, I can very well upload text and download text and then convert text (String) to byte[].

Comment: Since there is a method by name downloadToByteArray available, I wanted to use this.

Comment: If you want to use `downloadToByteArray ` to download the whole content, I think we need to get blob size before downloading

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210418/discussion-between-rax-and-jim-xu).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get blob size with java sdk, please refer to the following code

```
CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
        CloudBlobClient serviceClient = account.createCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer container = serviceClient.getContainerReference("test1");

        CloudBlob blob = container.getBlobReferenceFromServer("server.js");
        long size =blob.getProperties().getLength();
        System.out.println(size);
```

[image]

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.blobproperties.getlength?view=azure-java-legacy#com_microsoft_azure_storage_blob_BlobProperties_getLength__) and the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42801202/how-to-compute-azure-storage-container-size-in-java)