# How to Get CloudBlobDirectory Storage Utilised

Tags: c#, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to get the size of images on CloudBlobDirectory at one to go without iterate the List by C# code, as iteration taking time to load the page.

I have searched on net but all code showing by list iteration.

```
if (cloudBlobContainer.Exists() == true)
{
    CloudBlobDirectory folder = cloudBlobContainer.GetDirectoryReference(Subcontainer);
    foreach (var blobItem in folder.ListBlobs())
    {
        try
        {
            var blob = blobItem as CloudBlockBlob;
            if (blob != null)
                filesize += blob.Properties.Length;
        }
        catch { continue; }
    }
}
```

Time is only concerned it should return the result in a 2-3 sec as lots of images to show the occupied size of Azure storage.

Comment: Is your solution faster or slower than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376459/azure-storage-container-size/50096288#50096288 ?

Comment: it is very slower as I am checking for multiple Directory at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If time is your only concern, save "Length" to somewhere (database or to a file).

If uploading to blob is under your control, save length of file while uploading. If not, run a program at specific periods (for example at every 5 minutes) scan the files and save length of files.

Comment: You are welcome. Mark this answer as answer if you want.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to list blobs and calculate the total size.