# How to get the size of Azure Blob Container without blob list iteration?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm using Azure Blob storage .Net client library v11.

My azure blob container has more than 20 million files.
Listing blob and getting size of each blob is too much time consuming operation.

Looking for method to directly get the size of blob container.

Comment: Thank you for reply but your solution is not helpful for me. I know about Azure portal, I know we can calculate size one by one blob, But I'm looking for different solution.

Comment: ok, as far as I know, there is no direct way. But if you find a better solution, you can share it with us:).

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such api/sdk. Please keep eyes on this [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/840).

If you prefer using code, you must calculate them one by one. Here is an [exmaple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50096288/10185816).

Otherwise, you should check it via azure portal UI. There is an "Calculate size" button under each container -> Properties.

Answer (score 0):

Sign in the azure portal.
In the Azure portal, select Storage accounts.
From the list, choose a storage account.
In the Monitoring section, choose Insights (preview).

Comment: I'm using Azure .Net API, So expect solution using c# .Net Code.